# Python - How to keep the loop input after it answered?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

##### Main.py

In my current codes, it just stuck on the first question and not continuing the second questions. I want to make it loop until the last question answered and the loop will break/stop.

```
def main():
    Total = None

    with open("test.json", "r") as f:
        File = json.load(f)

    for i in File["data"].keys():
            Total = i # Total of the keys

    def do_game():
        num = 0
        num += 1

        if num > int(Total):
            print("No more questions are available.")
            return False # To break the loop but didn't work at all

        name = File["data"][str(num)]["type"]

        print("Enter type of filename (#{}) :".format(num))
        answer = input("Answer: ")

        if answer == name:
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            print("Incorrect!")

    while True:
        do_game() # I tried to loop this but didn't go well

main()
```

##### test.json

```
{
    "questions": {
        "1": {
            "question": "Video.mp4",
            "answer": "mp4"
        },
        "2": {
            "question": "cool.gif",
            "answer": "gif"
        },
        "3": {
            "question": "main.py",
            "answer": "python"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a closer look at the data in `File`, and the 1st line of `do_game()`. Try an [interactive debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) (Python comes with [pydb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html), but searching the web may turn up something that works better for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your code. Try this,

```
import json
def main():
    with open("test.json", "r") as f:
        File = json.load(f)
    total = len(File['questions'])
    for i in range(1,total+1):
        name = File["questions"][str(i)]["answer"]
        print("Enter type of filename (#{}) :".format(i))
        answer = input("Answer: ")
        print("Correct!" if answer==name else "Incorrect!")
    else:
        print("No more questions are available.")
        return False # To break the loop but didn't work at all

main()
```

**Output:**

```
Enter type of filename (#1) :
Answer: mp4
Correct!
Enter type of filename (#2) :
Answer: m
Incorrect!
Enter type of filename (#3) :
Answer: s
Incorrect!
No more questions are available.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your loop to:

```
while True:
    result = do_game()
    if result == False:
        break
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def main():
    Total = None

    with open("test.json", "r") as f:
        File = json.load(f)

    for i in File["data"].keys():
            Total = i # Total of the keys

    num = 1

    while num <= int(Total):

        name = File["data"][str(num)]["type"]

        print("Enter type of filename (#{}) :".format(num))
        answer = input("Answer: ")

        if answer == name:
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            print("Incorrect!")

        num += 1

main()
```

Since your data counting from 1 so we set `num = 1`.

Your code simply not run `question` 1 and 2 (which are first 2 item of your data). It doesn't make any loops through the file.

Answer (score 0):

Many little errors in your code.
Here is a functional code with some improvements. They are written as comments in the code.

```py
import json 

def do_game(jsonFile): #You need to put this function outside the main

    for question in jsonFile["questions"]: # Use a for loop over the json list
        filename = question["question"]

        print(f"Enter type of filename '{filename}'") #Use F-String
        answer = input("Answer: ")

        print("Correct!" if answer==question["answer"] else "Incorrect!")


def main():
    Total = None

    with open("test.json", "r") as f:
        jsonFile = json.load(f)

    do_game(jsonFile) # Do all the game's code in a function

# It's a good practice to execute the main funciton only if this file is the main file
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

As you have a list of questions, use a list in your json

```json
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "question": "Video.mp4",
            "answer": "mp4"
        },
        {
            "question": "cool.gif",
            "answer": "gif"
        },
        {
            "question": "main.py",
            "answer": "python"
        }
    ]
}
```